# Access Contacts iOS objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, contacts, contactpicker

I am trying to access user's contacts and fetch the selected phone number, but i am unable to implement same. I don't want to use ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate as it is deprecated ,i want to implement CNContactPickerViewController, how can i do so? as none answer related to this helped me out..

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem you are facing? Please post some code to further answer your question.

Make an object of `CNContactPickerViewController` and assign a delegate.

Implement `contactPicker:didSelectContact:` or `contactPicker:didSelectContacts:` delegates.